# How can I add a director name in line with author name in beamer?

Tags: beamer, titles

I would like to write director name in line with author name in a beamer like:

```
\author{Made by:\\Author name}
\director{Directed by:\\Director name}
```

but if I try to define director:

```
\def\director#1{\def\Director{#1}}\director{Director's Name}
```

Then it writes on the top of the first frame. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can adopt an approach based on `columns` environment:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
\title{My title}
\institute{My institute}
\author[Author name]{Made by:\\Author name} %<= used the short author name [] for the footline
\newcommand{\director}{Directed by:\\Director name}

% re-definition of the title page
\setbeamertemplate{title page}{
\centering
\begin{beamercolorbox}[rounded=true,shadow=true,sep=8pt,center]{title}
\inserttitle \par
\end{beamercolorbox}
\vfill
\begin{beamercolorbox}[leftskip=8cm,center,wd=0.7\textwidth]{author}
\begin{columns}[T]
\begin{column}{.49\textwidth}%
\centering
\insertauthor
\end{column}
\begin{column}{.49\textwidth}%
\centering
\director
\end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{beamercolorbox}
\vfill
\usebeamerfont{institute}\insertinstitute \par
\vfill
\centering
\insertdate\par
\vfill
}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Title}
example text
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

which gives you:

[image]

[image]

Notice that I adopted the short name for the `author` to not display in the footline the string `Made by:`.