# Adding fields to title page / customizing title page

Tags: beamer, titles

I need to add 3 supervisors to my titlepage. I found suggestions to make them part of \author, but it looks horrible, because every row is aligned by center (see picture). I would like to align somehow labels "Author" and "Supervisors" and in addition, all supervisors' names.

```
\author{Author: Me \\ Supervisors: First supervisor \\ Second \\ Third}
```

I tried to use tabular environment:

```
\author{\begin{tabular}[t]{p{3.5cm}}
test\\
test 1\\
\end{tabular}
}
```

But LaTeX gives an error:

> ! Use of \begin doesn't match its
>   definition.

[image]

Comment: You may have a look to: [How can I add a director name in line with author name in beamer?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/57977/13304).

Comment: @JLDiaz, I tried as you said. LaTeX doesn't like it. I updated the question.

Comment: @JLDiaz, could you move you comment ot answers? It works just great, thanks! Claudio, thank you also, I didn't want to change my current layout, if it's possible.

Comment: sorry, I misunderstood what you targeted: seeing JLDiaz's answer was illuminating :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A simple solution is to typeset the authors inside a `tabular` environment, which allows you to customize the desired layout.

The problem is that `\begin{tabular}` will fail if used in the preamble, so you have to delay your `\author` inizialization after `\begin{document}`

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
% For coherence, I move also \title, etc after \begin{document}

\title[Your Short Title]{Your Presentation}
\institute{Where You're From}
\author{\begin{tabular}{r@{ }l} 
Author:      & Me \\[1ex] 
Supervisors: & First\\
             & Second
\end{tabular}}
\date{Date of Presentation}

\begin{frame}
  \titlepage
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

As Gonzalo Medina noted in a comment, it is worth to mention that some beamer styles use the information provided in `\author` as part of the footer, or other part of the layout, and we don't want the whole tabular at that point. We can use the optional argument of `\author` to provide a "short version" which will be used at those places, for example:

```
\author[By Me]{\begin{tabular}{r@{ }l} 
  ...etc...
\end{tabular}}
```

Comment: Gonzalo suggests you to provide a short author as the final note in [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/57986/13304).

Comment: I was aware of the optional parameter that goes to footer. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @GonzaloMedina and Claudio, thanks for pointing that out. I've updated the answer.